# Capture program output and display it on a web page, with Spring Framework

Tags: command-line, spring-batch

OK i have a Spring Web Application, I am able to start the Spring Batch Job that also runs a command line shell or bat script, i can capture the output of that bat or shell script, my challenge is to display it on the web page as it is captured, an good ideas on how i can to that?